# change a created_at in string format to diffForHumans

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to pass a string containing the date from the created_at to a diffForHumans() format ?

```
{"time":"2021-03-25T18:49:22.000000Z"}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a parse() function within the Carbon/Carbon package, and you could try

```
$time = Carbon::parse($object->time)->diffForHumans();
```

Don't forget to include the Carbon package at the top of the file.
Hopefully this would help

Answer (score 1):

By default, Eloquent will cast the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns to instances of [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), which extends the PHP `DateTime` class and provides an assortment of helpful methods. You may cast additional date attributes by defining additional date casts within your model's `$cast` property array. Typically, dates should be cast using the `datetime` cast.

When defining a `date` or `datetime` cast, you may also specify the date's format. This format will be used when the [model is serialized to an array or JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization):

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be cast.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'datetime:Y-m-d',
];
```

When a column is cast as a date, you may set its value to a UNIX timestamp, date string `(Y-m-d)`, date-time `string`, or a `DateTime` / `Carbon` instance. The date's value will be correctly converted and stored in your database:

**You may customize the default serialization format for all of your model's dates by defining a `serializeDate` method on your model**. This method does not affect how your dates are formatted for storage in the database:

```
/**
 * Prepare a date for array / JSON serialization.
 *
 * @param  \DateTimeInterface  $date
 * @return string
 */
protected function serializeDate(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
    return $date->format('Y-m-d');
}
```

To specify the format that should be used when actually storing a model's dates within your database, you should define a `$dateFormat` property on your model:

```
/**
 * The storage format of the model's date columns.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $dateFormat = 'U';
```

Sice by default, Eloquent will cast the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns to instances of [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon) you can also simply do this.

```
$user->created_at->->diffForHumans();
```

Or if you have only one string then you can do it like this.

```
\Carbon\Carbon::parse($string)->diffForHumans();
```